# Express Guide hello.txt not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using the express guide here http://expressjs.com/guide.html#intro. I am getting a Cannot GET / error though. Anyone help?

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
app.get('/hello.txt', function(req, res){
  res.send('Hello World');
});
app.listen(10397);
console.log('Listening on port 10397');
```

Comment: Define a default route, such as `app.get('/', function(req, res) { res.send("Main"); });`

Comment: That worked. Why doesn't it work for the /hello.txt route though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open `http://localhost:10397/hello.txt` in your browser, it will work. You need a separate `app.get('/'...` route defined if you just want to load the root of the site: `http://localhost:10397`. That's what the "Cannot GET /" error is saying.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks I understand how it works now. That makes a lot more sense.